Count by occurrences
I have a query similar to:
select * 
from combined 
where valid_rating is null
   order by FIND_IN_SET(provider, 
    (select provider 
     from combined 
     where valid_rating is null group by provider order by count(1) desc)
   )

Basically, I am trying to order by the 'most important' provider first (the one with the largest count of items). How would I properly do this with an expression in the order_by clause, perhaps even using a window function?

The second argument to find_in_set() should be a comma-separated string. Your subquery doesn't return a single string.

@Barmar right it's the wrong function for that job...I'm trying to find a valid way to do this.

Use count() window function, partitioned by provider:
select c.*, count(*) over (partition by provider) cnt
from combined c
where valid_rating is null
order by cnt desc


exactly, that is what I was looking for -- thanks!

Join with the subquery that returns the counts, then order by the counts.
SELECT c.*, ct.count
FROM combined AS c
JOIN (
    SELECT provider, COUNT(*) AS count
    FROM provider
    GROUP BY provider
) AS ct ON c.provider = ct.provider
ORDER BY count DESC

